# How to rescale raster layer in R?

Tags: r, raster

I have a stacked raster layer of a world map that I am trying to rescale from -3.131791 to 3.387701 to 0 to 1. I followed [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194814/rescale-raster-in-r) and the first method gives me max(x) = 1 but for some reason min(x) becomes 3.127125e-08. The second method gives me a range of 0 to 1 but when I plot it out my raster layer just becomes a grainy rectangle like this:
 [image: a grainy rectangle like this].

Here is my code:

```
## PCA ##
PCA1 <- rasterPCA(img=layers, nComp=1, spca=TRUE)

## Rescale 1 ##
rescale <- function(x, x.min = -3.131791, x.max = 3.387701, new.min = 1, new.max = 0) {
  if(is.null(x.min)) {x.min = min(x)}
  if(is.null(x.max)) {x.max = max(x)}
  new.min + (x - x.min) * ((new.max - new.min) / (x.max - x.min))
  }

PCAscaled1 <- calc(PCA1$map[[1]], rescale) #rescaled and inverted
plot(PCAscaled1)

## Rescale 2 ##
r <- PCAscaled1
r[] <- runif(ncell(PCAscaled1),-3.127125e-08,1) 
r.min=cellStats(r,"min")
r.max=cellStats(r,"max")
PCAscaled1a <- (r-r.min)/(r.max-r.min)
plot(PCAscaled1a)
```

These are the parameters for the original raster in case it's relevant:

```
> PCA1$map[[1]]
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1352, 3570, 4826640  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent      : -177, 180, -56.07567, 79.12433  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /private/var/folders/3c/tsrm9qxs7t323jrz5k8h4d600000gn/T/RtmpKORCX5/raster/r_tmp_2018-11-17_002746_40497_32387.grd 
names       : PC1 
values      : -3.131791, 3.387701  (min, max)
```

I tried to see if any of the individual raster layers I used was the problem, and found out that all but one could be scaled to 0 to 1. But even when I exclude that raster layer I'm still not able to rescale it to 0 to 1. I also tried first rescaling all the individual raster layers then stacking them, but then the range of the stacked raster doesn't stay at 0 to 1 (I then tried to rescale that too but it still doesn't work).

If anyone knows what's wrong I'll really appreciate answers! If there is a different method of rescaling please let me know, I'll try that as well.

Comment: In Funtion `rescale`, you reversed max and min values:`new.min` should be 0, but you define as `new.min=1`. Neither do `new.max`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This was intentional because I wanted to inverse the raster layer.